# How to configure an Ingress to access all pods from a DaemonSet?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, daemonset

I'm using hardware-dependents pods; in my K8s, I instantiate my pods with a DaemonSet.

Now I want to access those pods with an URL like `https://domain/{pod-hostname}/`

My use case is a bit more tedious than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710419/access-to-all-kubernetes-statefulset-pods-via-ingress). my pods' names are not predefined.

Moreover, I also need a REST entry point to list my pod's name or hostname.

Comment: thinking out loud 1-you can get the pod name with metadata.name and store it into an env variable. 2-create a loadbalancer service. 3-create an ingress controller with nginx and https and inject the variable from #1

Comment: this can be useful for the api https://livebook.manning.com/book/kubernetes-in-action/chapter-8/1

Comment: I almost solved the issue, but I still have to find the correct ingress configuration. I do not know how to access the pod from an ingress without using a service. Of creating a service per pod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I publish a Docker Image to solve my issue: [urielch/dyn-ingress](https://hub.docker.com/r/urielch/dyn-ingress)

My YAML configuration is in the Docker doc.

This Container add label on each pod, then use this label to create a service per pod, and then update an existing Ingress to reach each node with a path //

feel free to test it.
[the source code is here](https://github.com/UrielCh/dyn-ingress)